# How to parse MIB output from FC switch to OID?

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, snmp, mib

I trying to find specific WWN address from FC switch table in order to get port ID and change admin state (I already have the WWN address).
I using SNMP that return WWN table for it and I get output like this:

```
      In [39]: netsnmp.snmpwalk('.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.297.1.1.16.1.2',Version = 2,DestHost = 'lab-fc',Community = 'public')

      Out[39]:('P\x01C\x80\x18j\xc3\x88\x10\x08\x00\x01')
```

How I can convert this output to OID number?

Comment: I want to find correlation of  the physical location of the port on the switch with WWN (i.e., module 2/port 5 or fc2/5) via SNMP?

Answer (score 1):

The netsnmp library is returning you an octet string, which is essentially binary.  According to the [Cisco definition](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=fcsAttachPortName) of the port ID, the first 8 bytes is the WWN.

```
import netsnmp
import struct
import binascii

portid = netsnmp.snmpwalk('.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.297.1.1.16.1.2',Version = 2,DestHost = 'lab-fc',Community = 'public')
print ''.join(binascii.hexlify(i) for i in struct.unpack_from('cccccccc', s))
```

Output

```
'50014380186ac388'
```

Does that look like the right WWN?